# How can i make a multi language nativescript vue app?

Tags: nativescript, multilingual, nativescript-vue, vue-i18n

I need to have over 10 language in my Nativescript-vue app. I have looked at "vue-i18next" but i don't  understand how it works with single file components. I don't  understand how it will work if i have exempel app.vue, register.vue, login.vue and so on.. The docs didn't show how to do it on single file components.
Can someone give me a example with nativescript-vue "vue-i18next" or another language plugin? Just show me one single file component how its done ;)

Comment: What you have tried so far, did you refer the package's official docs? Did you implement the package, do you find any specific errors?

Comment: You could try this plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-i18n

Comment: What do you want to achieve with those languages, do people need to able to change the language?

Comment: I solved it with: nativescript-localize. @Steven i will have the app in contreys where it different languages